# Execute ruby script without .rb extension?

Tags: ruby, linux, path

I know you can execute a script without typing "ruby" before the file name if you add a shebang, but how do you execute it without a file extension so instead of "filename.rb" you can use just "filename".

And, what's the norm/best-practice for deploying Ruby programs, i.e. file location and path etc.?

Comment: "And, what's the norm/best-practice for deploying Ruby programs, i.e. file location and path etc.?" This should be asked as a separate question as it's not closely related to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In linux, the information about the interpreter is usually taken from the shebang line, not from the extension. That's why you basically don't need the extension (but usually need the execute bit in the file attributes).

I don't know what are the traditions in Ruby about file naming (is it considered a good thing or not to include an extension), but it's generally a good idea to follow it (whatever it is).

Comment: Okie doke so just remove the .rb?

Comment: Just follow the general convention or whatever you feel is right. The extension is not obligatory, you can put it (or not) at your will.

Comment: Which is fine of course, but means my text editor won't pick up on which syntax highlighting to use.. So maybe just use "myfile" as a wrapper that calls out to "otherfile.rb"?

Comment: Doesn't your editor pick up the information from shebang line? Anyway, nothing is wrong in leaving the `.rb` extension for the main program, if you find it convenient (except directly exposing the language as a part of name, which you might consider aesthetically wrong). The same way, nothing is wrong in removing the extension (except perhaps your text editor not knowing how to highlight it).

Comment: Actually yeah good point! I've started using vim this last month so it probably will work fine! Thanks! One last thing how are ruby programs with multiple files usually deployed? Do I just put the main file and a folder for the other junk in /usr/bin ?  Thank again!

Comment: Oh, I don't know about the deployment, I'm basically a Windows guy. I would put the files other that the main one into a subfolder, but this may be wrong; I would perhaps ask someone with more Linux background.

Comment: @Daniel Upton "how are ruby programs with multiple files usually deployed?", This needs to be asked as a separate question. It really has nothing to do with the current question.

Comment: @ Daniel Upton, "my text editor won't pick up on which syntax highlighting to use." It's more significant than that. All OSes now look at the extension one way or another, and use that to help decide what application(s) should be used to open the file. Mac OS used a separate mechanism that ignored extensions for many years, but when Mac OS 10 was released they had to begin honoring extensions too, because of the BSD/Unix underpinnings. So, removing the extension can cause odd/undesirable behavior. Rather than worry about the extensions, learn to use word completion at the command-line.